# Autolaunch the app after tablet restart in flutter

Tags: flutter, kotlin

I want the flutter application to automatically launch after tablet is restarted.
I currently use the app as default home app to do this auto launching but
I have encountered functionality issues like:
*When I input a password in a textbox it will only display when I close the keyboard
*When I click the combo box , the dropdown list will only display when I click the overview button of the tablet
I am not sure what could be causing this issue.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

This issues only occur when the lock screen is set and relaunching of app is done before unlocking the screen .

I tried to restart the app using the ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED but it is issue still occur when the tablet was set to lock screen.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.